# multiple turtlebots on wireless network

Tags: ros, wireless, wifi, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have 10 turtlebots (version 1, the white one) that I'm trying to operate on a wifi network (g wireless standard). Any three of them together work fine but as soon as I add a fourth the *turtlebot_node* starts throwing lots of error messages about not being able to read data from the iCreate properly and the system grinds to a halt. I switched it over to a wired network and got all 10 running great with a peak network bandwidth of 9KBps, which isn't really that much. Is there something specific to the *turtlebot_node* that struggles with message latency or wifi in general?

Right now my alternatives are:

1. rewrite the *turtlebot_node* to make it more tolerant of infrequent message
2. combine all the nodes on each turtlebot using nodelets
3. reorganize the system as a multi-master network, with one master on each turtlebot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65640/multiple-turtlebots-on-wireless-network/) by [andrewlybarger](https://answers.ros.org/users/5203/andrewlybarger/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rafael](https://answers.ros.org/users/5062/rafael/) on 2013-06-24**:
Hi, how are they running in the same network? Are they running independently or they can share topics?

**Comment by [andrewlybarger](https://answers.ros.org/users/5203/andrewlybarger/) on 2013-06-26**:
I'm quite certain that it is possible to run 4 or more turtlebots together, the question is does the stock turtlebot_node need to modified or the network/ros configuration. Right now all of the turtlebots are using a single ros master, which is running on my desktop machine.

**Comment by [Rafael](https://answers.ros.org/users/5062/rafael/) on 2013-06-26**:
Thanks Andrew, I have a question setup regarding how to do that single ros master multi-robot config. I would be very grateful if you could please take a look at it and give me an idea of how you got this to work. I tried it with namespaces following a suggestion here but it has been a dead end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest that you debug a little bit deeper into the root cause.  I know of demos with 4 or more TurtleBots on the same wireless network.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0